# Mongoose search keywords and save between two collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

I am new to Mongoose. I am creating a recipe search app. I try to generate keywords from ingredient strings. By using mongoose "$lookup". I have two mongoose Schemas **Recipe**, **FoodLibrary** and their collections are "**recipes**", "**foodlibraries**".

Recipe schema collection looks like this:

```
title: "Kung Pao Tofu"
ingredients:
 0: "1 14-ounce package extra firm tofu, drained"
 1: "¼ cup plus 2 tablespoons reduced sodium or gluten-free soy sauce"
 2: "3 tablespoons cornstarch, divided"
 3: "1 2-inch piece ginger, minced"
```

FoodLibrary schema collection looks like this:

```
name: "almond"
category: "nuts and beans"
```

---

```
name: "cucumber"
category: "vegetables"
```

I want to look into foodlibraries collection for each ingredients array element and match the closest word then save it like this:

```
title: "Kung Pao Tofu"
ingredients:
 0: "1 14-ounce package extra firm tofu, drained"
 1: "¼ cup plus 2 tablespoons reduced sodium or gluten-free soy sauce"
 2: "3 tablespoons cornstarch, divided"
 3: "1 2-inch piece ginger, minced"
keywords:
 0: "tofu"
 1: "soy sauce"
 2: "cornstarch"
 3: "ginger"
```

I tried this code but doesn't seem working for this case:

```
Recipe.aggregate([
      { "$unwind": { "path": "$ingredients" }},
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": "foodlibraries",
        "localField": "ingredients",
        "foreignField": "name",
        "as": "keywords"
      }},
    ])
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The $lookup cannot match the `name` with the `ingredients`. Because the match is a _equality_ condition. Somehow, you have to match the `name` with its value _within_ the `ingredients`. Maybe, something like [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/index.html) _or_  [Text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/index.html).

Comment: Maybe you can consider keeping the food reference inside the ingredient when you create a recipe.